# Bundle Angular.JS templates with Webpack 4

Tags: angularjs, webpack, webpack-4

I have a hybrid project with both AngularJS 1.x and Angular 6 code.
I'm trying to bundle all the .html templates to a js file so that all the following AngularJS calls that are done in *.js files -

```
.directive('myDirective', [
    function () {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/components/.../derp/derp.html',

        ...
}}]);
```

will work.

I tried using `ngtemplate-loader` with the following rule:

```
{
    test: /\/(components|views)\/.*?\.html$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'ngtemplate-loader'
      },
      {
        loader: 'html-loader'
      }
    ]
}
```

and no cigar.. as I understand it, it'll only work for `require(..)` calls and not for plain string urls.. 
I didn't find any solution that works with js files that don't support `require`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what solved the issue for me was to convert all my states from

```
.state('...', {
    url: '...'
    templateUrl: './a/b/c.html',
    controller: '...'
})
```

to

```
.state('...', {
    url: '...'
    templateUrl: require('./a/b/c.html'),
    controller: '...'
})
```

while using the following webpack rule

```
{
    test: /\.html$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'ngtemplate-loader',
        options: {
          relativeTo: path.resolve(__dirname, "app")
        }
      },
      {
        loader: 'html-loader'
      }
    ],
    exclude: [
      /index\.html$/
    ]
}
```

and it worked! I didn't have to change any other `templateUrl: ...` statements throughout the code :)

Answer (score 0):

you can import the html file in your js file. and then try to use the reference.

```
 var template = require('/components/.../derp/derp.html')   
 app.directive('myDirective', [
    function () {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: template,

        ...
}}]);
```

and instead of `templateUrl` use `template` only.